# How to detect a key-press in python with raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, keyboard, root, raspberry-pi4

I'm using the keyboard module thing and it comes up with this error.

I have seen other posts and have done as they say and used sudo pip3 install keyboard yet it still does not work.

```
import keyboard
loop = ""


while loop == "":

    if keyboard.read_key() == "w":
        print("You pressed w")



    if keyboard.read_key() == "a":


        print("You pressed a")

    if keyboard.read_key() == "s":
        print("You pressed s")



    if keyboard.read_key() == "d":
        print("You pressed d")
```

```
>>> 
==================== RESTART: /home/pi/Desktop/turret.py ====================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/turret.py", line 7, in <module>
    if keyboard.read_key() == "w":
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 935, in read_key
    event = read_event(suppress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 924, in read_event
    hooked = hook(queue.put, suppress=suppress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 461, in hook
    append(callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 67, in add_handler
    self.start_if_necessary()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 35, in start_if_necessary
    self.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 196, in init
    _os_keyboard.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 113, in init
    build_device()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 109, in build_device
    ensure_root()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 174, in ensure_root
    raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.
>>>
```

I run the code and get that error. I thought i did install it to root.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796147/import-error-you-must-be-root)?

Comment: you need to run the script as root

Comment: yes i did use sudo pip3 install keyboard - as stated in the second line on my question. It didn't seem to work however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to run your script as root it's meant to get started like `sudo python3 ./yourfile.py`

Don't forget to make the script executable by chmod +x.