# How to stop a while loop with a user input without interrupting the program?

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

How do I infinitely loop 5 led lights to keep turning on one after the other until the user inputs something? I don't want the user input to interrupt the loop. Right now everything works well except that in the middle of the loop the input interrupts the program.

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

print("Press h to exit the program")

while True:

    GPIO.setup(19,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(19,True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(19,False)

    GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(26,True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(26,False)

    GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(22,True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(22,False)

    GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(27,True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(27,False)

    GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(17,True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(17,False)

    x = input("")

    if (x == "h"):
        print("Exiting the program")
        break

    GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the raspberry-pi. When asking questions here, it's always best to provide a runnable [mre] and leave _everything_ out of it that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the third-party [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard) library to do this quite easily.

```
import keyboard

while True:
    print(1)
    print(2)
    print(3)
    print(4)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("h"):
       break
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried what you suggested but I've got a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard' error. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Since its a third party library you need to install it first. `pip install keyboard`

Comment: Apparently I had to do sudo pip3 install keyboard although I still have errors.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.

Comment: @Johnlewis https://stackoverflow.com/q/48796147/7942856