# ImportError in python keyboard library

Tags: python, subprocess, importerror, python-module, keyboard-python

I need to use from Keyboard library in python.
I installed with "sudo pip3 install keyboard" and if I do pip list keyboard appears.
when I run the Programm, I have Error.  Error is: "ImportError: you must be root to use this library on linux"
Why is happening this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796147/import-error-you-must-be-root

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import error: you must be root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796147/import-error-you-must-be-root)