# No module named 'keyboard' in Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, keyboard, pythonanywhere

I successfully installed the keyboard module with `pip install keyboard`. But when I run the code it says `No module named 'keyboard'`. All other modules run successfully after installing. I don't know what I am missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your python version and did you activate the virtual env before installing that module `workon the-name-of-your-virtualenv'` ?

Comment: Yes, I did activate the virtual env. Python version is 3.6.13

Comment: try this `pip3.6 install --user keyboard`

Comment: @amadousow ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.

Comment: try to change the version `pip3.7 install --user keyboard`

Comment: @amadousow Still  No module named 'keyboard'

Comment: first of all your python version is 3.6.13  and when you tried` pip3.6 install --user keyboard it gives an error`  and with this `pip3.7 install --user keyboard` it works fine.The pip command on its own installs modules for an other python version; it looks like your website is using 3.6. This help page(https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/) explains how to install modules for different Python versions.

Comment: It still shows the error

Comment: Where do you get the error?  Make sure you've installed the package for the same version of Python / virtualenv that's running your code.

Comment: @caseneuve Yes, it's the same python version. The error is when I run the Django server.  It shows `No module named 'keyboard'`

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the error -- is it in a console?  If it is, does the name of the virtualenv appear in the console prompt?

Comment: @GilesThomas Nope it isn't in the console. It's on the Django webpage.

Comment: Have you specified the virtualenv on the "Web" page inside PythonAnywhere?

Comment: @GilesThomas  specified it but now I'm getting some other kind of error: `ImportError at /type/
You must be root to use this library on linux.`

Comment: I looked at the answers in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796147/import-error-you-must-be-root). When I use `sudo pip3 install keyboard`, it says `bash: sudo: command not found`

Comment: What are you trying to use the library for?

Comment: @GilesThomas Trying to make a typing test website

Comment: Right, but more specifically, what calls are you making to the library and what are you expecting it to do?  Remember that code that is running on PythonAnywhere is running on a remote server and is only connected to your keyboard over a complex mix of web technologies which it will see as looking like a remote SSH connection.  You don't have the same low-level hardware access to the keyboard as you would if you were running your Python code on a local computer with the keyboard plugged directly in.

Comment: @GilesThomas Yeah, that's why I'm thinking to shift to JS for the key input. Thanks for your help and time!!