# Keyboard in pydroid 3

Tags: python, keyboard, pydroid

I wrote a code, which writes numbers with some mistakes for discord. I checked on my laptop, it's worked, but on phone pydroid it isn't working.
code:

```
import keyboard as kb
import random as rd
import time as tm
x = 0
tm.sleep(10)
z = x+20
while True:
    x+=1
    if x == z and 0:
        tm.sleep(100)
        z = rd.randint(z+100,z+500)
    kb.write(str(x))
    if rd.randint(1,20) == 1:
        if rd.choice([True,False]):
            kb.write(str(rd.randint(min((x-1)%10,(x+1)%10),max((x-1)%10,(x+1)%10))))
        else:
            kb.write("\\")
    tm.sleep(2)
    kb.write("\n")
```

Error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
...
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.

[Program finished]
```l0
````

Answer (score 0):

Similar post : [Import error: you must be root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796147/iport-error-you-must-be-root)

Try `sudo pip3 install keyboard` .

Comment: sudo:not found.

Comment: I wrote a code on phone, but not working. I have terminal.

Comment: install using sudo on your main machine not on the device.

Comment: No, I need only for phone

Comment: All main functions are suggested to the phone

Comment: Just install it using sudo on your main machine.

Comment: How to install on phone?